# Getting customized fonts to upload in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to make the below code work to upload the font TrashHand to my website in Wordpress. I have edited out the website name but otherwise the code remains the same.

The code is contained in my style.css file and I know that Wordpress is reading the file because when I change the color line below, it changes the color of the text.

I also know that my url is correct because if I paste the url into my browser, the font downloads automatically.

I may be making a dumb mistake as I am a novice at css, but any help would be much appreciated.

```
@font-face {
font-family: TrashHand;  
src: url(##websitename##.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-

child/fonts/TrashHand.ttf); 
}

p {
    font-family: TrashHand;
    color: green;
}

h1 {
    font-family: TrashHand;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change these lines

```
src: url(##websitename##.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/fonts/TrashHand.ttf); 
}
```

to

```
src: url(/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/fonts/TrashHand.ttf); 
}
```

No websitename is needed as the **src** is looking for an **absolute URL**

Answer (score 0):

you should use .woff and .woff2 font format with .ttf

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'TrashHand';
         url('##websitename##.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/fonts/TrashHand.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('##websitename##.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/fonts/TrashHand.woff') format('woff'),
         url('##websitename##.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/fonts/TrashHand.ttf') format('truetype'),
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

you can generate woff and woff2 online using your .ttf file.